# JavaScript Regex Match all occurances where a word has "Alternate" or "Primary

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a regex that works nearly as intended. Here is the example

https://regex101.com/r/wW9oL7/2

```
\bprimary\b|\balternate\b
```

matches all occurrences of Alternate or Primary case insensitive. The issue is, it does not pick up matches where the leading characters of the word, or following characters are different.

Here are my Test cases. I would like the last 3 to match as well.

> Primary primary alternate Alternate PrimeTime facebook Christopher Primative PrimaryYY 1Primary1
>     YYPrimaryze

for clarification, I would like it to match `YYPrimaryze` , `1Primary1` , `PrimaryYY`

Comment: If you want it to match anywhere in a string, why are you only matching at word boundaries? `\bprimary\b` vs. `primary`

Comment: Obviously, you need to remove the word boundaries... Why are they there in first place?

Comment: Oh wow. That was incredibly more simple than i thought `primary|alternate` is all I needed!

Comment: To the downvoter(s), OP did attempt this at regex 101 and post a link, no matter how naive doesn't that deserve not being downvoted? Just sayin...

Comment: try:- `/\w*(primary|alternate)\w*/gi`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to match `primary` and `alternate` as complete words **and also within** words? Then simply extend your regex to allow for word characters `\w` before and after your match:

```
\b\w*(primary|alternate)\w*\b
```

Demo:

```js
var string = "Primary primary alternate Alternate PrimeTime facebook Christopher Primative PrimaryYY 1Primary1 YYPrimaryze";
    
var matches = string.match(/\b\w*(primary|alternate)\w*\b/gi);

console.log(matches); // ["Primary", "primary", "alternate", "Alternate", "PrimaryYY", "1Primary1", "YYPrimaryze"]
```

See also https://regex101.com/r/wW9oL7/3

Answer (score 0):

If you need to just check if a string has a `primary` or a `alternate` substring (case insensitive), you can split the string with a space and check if any of the text chunks (converted to lower case) have either `primary` or `alternate` strings:

```js
var str = 'Primary primary alternate Alternate PrimeTime facebook Christopher \nPrimative PrimaryYY 1Primary1 YYPrimaryze';
var res = str.split(" ").filter(function(x) {  
 return x.toLowerCase().indexOf("primary") > -1 ||  
           x.toLowerCase().indexOf("alternate") > -1;
  }
);
document.body.innerHTML = "<pre>" + JSON.stringify(res, 0, 4) + "</pre>";
```

If you need to check that with a regex, surely, [word boundaries](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html)  must be removed.

```js
var re = /[a-z]*(?:primary|alternate)[a-z]*/gi; 
var str = 'Primary primary alternate Alternate PrimeTime facebook Christopher \nPrimative PrimaryYY 1Primary1 YYPrimaryze';
document.body.innerHTML = "<pre>" + JSON.stringify(str.match(re), 0, 4) + "</pre>";
```

The `[a-z]*` that match 0+ ASCII letters are used to just match any letters before or after the search terms you have, that part can be omitted if you just want to count matches.